# Iframe dosent work

Tags: javascript, arrays, iframe, parent-child

I have code:

```
<iframe src="in1.html" width="400" height="300" id="f1">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<script>
var childFrame = document.getElementById("f1").contentWindow;
childFrame.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
</script>
```

When i load page yellow is show on but then white background is load. Why?

Comment: You probably have to wait for the iframe to load before you can change it

Comment: but my script is below <iframe>

Comment: That doesn't help much, the iframe still has to **load** the content

Comment: so what i can wait for the frame to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to wait for the iframe to load ....

```
iframe src="in1.html" width="400" height="300" id="f1">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<script>
    var childFrame = document.getElementById("f1");

    childFrame.onload = function() {
        var cWindow = childFrame.contentWindow;
        cWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: yeah ! it amazing, thanks so much, and greeting from Poland